# How to configure log4j in Eclipse to view debug messages of Maven dependency library?

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I have a Maven project in Eclipse that has the following dependencies, among others:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hyperledger.fabric-sdk-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>fabric-sdk-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hyperledger.fabric</groupId>
    <artifactId>fabric-gateway-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

As part of my troubleshooting efforts, I would like to use log4j (or a similar library) to view the debug output that originates from these libraries. In my `src/main/resources` folder I have the following `log4j.properties` file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I have changed the level of `rootLogger` to `DEBUG` but I am still unable to see the debug messages.

I would like to look at the debug messages of one or more specific classes - `org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.NetworkConfig` for instance. How should I configure my `log4j.properties` to achieve this?

---

Update: I have just been made aware of the log4j security vulnerability. Nevertheless, I would like to continue with seeking help for my question as I have confidence that the situation will be resolved soon.

Comment: Are you aware of recent security issues with Log4j?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Sorry, I'm not aware of this. I will need to read up on those.

Comment: No need to apologize, just wanted to make sure that you’re not exposed :) It was only recently announced.